# please suggest a good XMPP server with an automatic account registration

Tags: xmpp

Maybe you could suggest a good XMPP server, such as icq.com , jabber or livejournal, that would accept automatic account registration from an xmpp client, not from their website.

Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Many servers support [XEP-77](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html).  You can find a list here:

http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/